# Alignment in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I want use this options:

```
\arrow[d, 
       start anchor={[xshift=0.35cm]south west},
       end   anchor={[xshift=0.35cm]north west}]
```

but it is a very long code. Is there a way in order to have a shorter code? for instance:

```
       \arrow[d,startcode,endcode]
```

where

```
    startcode STAND FOR start anchor={[xshift=0.35cm]south west} 
    endcode   STAND FOR end   anchor={[xshift=0.35cm]north west}
```

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example. Then it is a lot easier for others to help, as they do not need to guess parts of your example document (guesses that might not apply to your usecase)

Comment: Can't you just say `\tikzset{startcode/.style={ start anchor={[xshift=0.35cm]south west}},endcode/.style={end   anchor={[xshift=0.35cm]north west}}}`? As pointed out by @daleif, one would need an MWE to test this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by marmot in his comment works, but the correct macro is `\tikzcdset`, not `\tikzset`.

If this doesn't match your needs, please add a *complete* minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
    startcode/.style={
        start anchor={[xshift=0.35cm]south west}
        },
    endcode/.style={
        end anchor={[xshift=0.35cm]north west}
    }
}

\begin{document}
Just to compare the two arrows with and without \texttt{startcode} and \texttt{endcode}:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[d,startcode,endcode] & A \ar[d]\\
B & B
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]